# mouseup on the document scroll button

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseup

This code is working, when the mouse is "UP" in the document:

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function () {
    alert("mouseup");
});
```

But how to make `alert()`, when the mouse is UP on the scroll button?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the ["scroll" event handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  alert("mouseup");
});
```

Comment: But your code is working, when scroll happens. I want alert(), when mouse "UP" on the scroll button. tell please, js can't make this ?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want some happened, when user "upped" mouse on site (html document) or on scroll button and i dont know how make mouse up on scroll button.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery API:

```
.mouseup( handler(eventObject) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 2){                //2 is the code for the middle button
        //some codes...
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3wmaK/